# Seperate & Calculate Values inside an objects of array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that I want to separate them into another variable that display the results example :

```
const objArray = 
  { name : [ 'hanna', 'layla', 'angela', 'lilly', 'hanna', 'layla' ]
  , age  : [ 20, 19, 20, 33, 40, 22 ] 
  }
```

I want to check how many duplicated name is inside names object then calculate it with % is this is the out I want to reach

```
name : [ hanna is 30% , layla is 30% , angela is 20% ,layla is 20% ]
    
age : [ 20 is 32% , 19 is 17% , 33 is 17% , 40 is 17% , 22 is 17% ]
```

for example we found hanna 2 times and her score should be 30% from total name array because she is found 2 times than others and similar to the age it calculate how many same age inside this array in % of 100% of total array.

Comment: Where do you get these percentages from? Why 30%, why 20%? It seems unrelated to multiples of 1/6.

Comment: its just an example because hanna found 2 times so she has a higher % than others , i want to calculate the % of that name inside an array

Comment: OK, but **how** did you get to 30%? Why not 35% or 33% or 32%? Are you saying that anything goes as long as it is a bit more than the other percentage? Is there no significance to what those percentages actually mean? Isn't it true that Hanna occurs twice as many times as Angela? Then why did you choose 30% and 20% which do not relate like that to eachother?

Comment: `objArray` (as defined in the question as: `{ name: ['hanna', ...], age : [ 20, ... ] }` is not a javascript array, based on my understanding.

Comment: it shouldn't be exactly 30% , it can be any number like 30% or 35% or any number , it was just an example

Comment: @jsN00b this is called array of object

Comment: `2` times on `6` is `33.3333 %` not `30 %`. and  `1` time on `6` is `16.6666 %` not `20 %`.

Comment: @MisterJojo yes it was just an output example , not the right numbers

Comment: this is computuer science, not fantasy science

Comment: just wanted a method so i can calculate each % of the same name that is inside an array , that is all i wanted to ask but i got my question closed and alot of dislikes instead :(

Comment: the next time you ask a question I hope you have [read the help on how to write a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and try to not let it be known that your approximations are reliable results

Comment: @MisterJojo i know every rule inside stackoverflow but the case that i am not good at english to explain things clearly makes my questions always closed , i always do my best to question and answer questions but it maybe that my english is not good that is the case :(

Comment: this is just about math, not fluency in English. me neither my english is not very good, but here everyone speaks globish anyway, not english.

Answer (score 1):

```
const {name, age} = objectStr;
//now you have name and age array
const nameMap = {}
name.map((x)=>{
   const curCount = nameMap[x]?nameMap[x]:0;
   nameMap[x] = curCount+1;
})
```

now you have nameMap which contains mapping of name and its occurrences
use this map to calculate percentage

Comment: its working but is there anyway to do looping inside name , age variables because it should be dynamic because what if i have like 10 or more objects it would be hard to make 10 maps for each one

Comment: yes, so what you can do is make a function to calculate percentage on the basis of array it receives, and then just iterate over objArray
```objArray.map(key=>calulatePercentage(objArray,key))```
and calulatePercentage will return object with percentages

Comment: will try this function and will try to make it work

Comment: `console.log(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(objArray).map(([k, v]) => {if (v && Array.isArray(v) && v.length) {return ([k, v.reduce((acc, elt) => {acc[elt] ??= 0;acc[elt]++;return acc;},{})]);} else {return ([k, v]);}})));` ---> this doesn't get percentages - but very close, it gets number of times. So, just divide by length & you get percentages, I think.